# DebugDiag giving no stacktrace for .NET 4.6 MVC5 application

Tags: performance, .net-4.6, debugdiag

I'm trying to debug some CPU issues caused by a .NET 4.6 MVC5 application by analyzing a dump created by DebugDiag 2.1.0.7. I'm finding even after loading custom .pdb symbols I'm still not getting stacktrack information in the generated report:

[image]

The error that the report displays is

```
Type: Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.ClrDiagnosticsException
Message:  This runtime is not initialized and contains no data.
```

[image]

I note that DebugDiag version 1.2 didn't support .NET 4.0+. Could DebugDiag 2.1 perhaps not support .NET 4.6?

Answer (score 0):

My CPU issues came down to a third-party piece of software that I was initialising in the wrong place. It needed to be initialised in `Application_Start()` and instead I was doing it in `Application_BeginRequest()`. Whoops! If you're experiencing this, and are scrambling around trying to debug issues in your production app like I was, make sure you check out the Global.asax for anything like this.

I'm guessing that the StackTrace issues with DebugDiag were related to where in the application lifecycle that the code causing the CPU problem was occurring.